# Symfony2 ManyToMany inverse result

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, entity

I have 3 entities.

- users
- groups
- user_groups

Users entity contains the users, Groups contains groups and there is ManyToMany relationship between these two entities with user_groups.

In my Users entity I can get those groups which are assigned to my user:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Groups", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_groups",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $groups;
```

This is plain and simple, but how can I get those groups which are NOT assigned to my user?

Is there any method to get "inverse result" of a ManyToMany relationship?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **NOT MEMBER OF** expression in your queryBuilder :

```
...
->andWhere(':user NOT MEMBER OF g.users')
->setParameter('user', $user)
...
```